# Passing delimiter as command line argument in scala and use it to split a string

Tags: scala

I have a scala program where I take "\t" as a command line input.

Inside the program I want to split a string on the basis of the delimiter passed from command line.

```
val splitter = args(0).charAt(0)

if(splitter == '\t')
      println("true")
else
     println("false")
```

This prints "false" and splitter "\".

The above method works for "," comma delimiter.

Please suggest how can I pass a tab or any other delimiter as command line parameter and use it for the splitting purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because if you're passing "\t" in on the command line, then it's coming in as a two-character string `\t`, not a single-character tab.  To do what you want, you can't just take the first character (`charAt(0)`) since you'll miss the `t`.  Instead you'll have to unescape it by converting from the string `\t` to the tab character.

An easy way:

```
val splitter = args(0) match {
  case "\\t" => '\t'
  case x => x.head     // same as x.charAt(0)
}
```